# Login redirection error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, redirect

I am building a web application i ve a login jsp form which will be redirected to a servlet...

My servlet code:

```
Login login=new Login();
        login.setUserName(request.getParameter("txtUsername"));
        login.setPassWord(request.getParameter("txtPassword"));

        LoginService ls=new LoginService();
        ls.loginValidate(login);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
 }
```

and from their to service class:

My service class code:

```
public class LoginService {
    Login login=null;

    public Login loginValidate(Login login) {
        validateLogin(login);
        return login;
    }

    private void validateLogin(Login login) {
        this.login=login;
         if(login!=null){
       LoginDAO ld=new LoginDAO();
       DataSource dataSource=new DataSource();
       ld.setDataSource(dataSource);
        ld.validate(login);

    }
    }
}


    }
```

and from their to DAO

My LoginDAO:

```
public class LoginDAO {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public  boolean validate(Login login){
        boolean status=true;
        String sql="select * from Login where UserName=? and PassWord=?";

        Connection conn = null;
        try{
        conn = dataSource.createConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,login.getUserName());
        ps.setString(2,login.getPassWord());
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        status=rs.next();
        }

        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
        }
        return status;
}
}
```

when i type the correct username and password its redirecting to success page(Login.jsp in this context) and even if i type wrong un and pw its redirecting i do understand why because after method call in servlet i have dispatched it to login.jsp so in any condition it will redirect me to success page. How to resolve this... Help needed.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/21720397/how-to-write-custom-exceptions-for-login-in-java/21720945 this is the same quetion you asked before.

Comment: yes i didnt get the expected answer there so i refined it excluding custom exception and posted a new question...

Comment: same suggestions are are coming like my previous ans to you. Have you understand what I have to say in that answer..?

Comment: ya but am trying to change the program as you all said but same thing is happening no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your validate method in LoginDAO, if the username and password is not present in the table, it will return an empty Resultset. Based on whether the result set is empty or not return the boolean value to the Servlet.

```
public  boolean validate(Login login)
{
  boolean status=true;
...
...
...
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

if (!rs.next()){
status=false;
}

return status;

}
```

In the servlet you can get the returned value in a parameter and based on its value redirect it to the appropriate success or error page

```
Boolean check=ls.loginValidate(login);

if(check==true) 
{
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
}
else
{
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

The LoginService class can have only 1 method loginValidate which should return a boolean

```
public boolean loginValidate(Login login) {

Boolean check=false;

         if(login!=null){
       LoginDAO ld=new LoginDAO();
       DataSource dataSource=new DataSource();
       ld.setDataSource(dataSource);
        check=ld.validate(login);
       }
return check;
    }
```

Comment: i tried this way at Boolean check=ls.loginValidate(login); it showed an error loginValidate should be changed to boolean so i changed and made it return true; but still the same problem

Comment: Thats because the loginValidate() method in LoginService returns a Login type... Change that methods return type to boolean. And I didn't understand why there was a need to create 2 methods with similar confusing names. I think only 1 method loginValidate() as shown in the edited answer should be enough.

Comment: no i changed that one method only to boolean and made it return true; before it was returning login object now i changed it to boolean but same thing is happening no change in the output....

Comment: if you are still redirected to Login.jsp even after entering the wrong username and password, it means that the method validate in LoginDAO is returning 'true' which implies that your result set after exectuing the query is not empty (The if block where status variable is changed to false is not being executed. Just test that once by giving a print command in that if block.) Also check if there is a row with all null values in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You have a validate method that returns a boolean. Use this method result to redirect the user back to the login page with some error message when the password doesn't match.

Ps. This is not safe to login storing the plain password in the db. You must store it encrypted. Most containers have solutions for the authentication built in.